# Re write SQL windowing function (rank over partition() ) without using windowing function

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Windowing functions were introduced in hive 12.0 however, I am unable to use a newer version of Hive. Is it possible to re write/express the following hive of SQL in HiveQL?

```
 select userid, siteid, eventdate, 
 count(*) over(partition by userid, siteid order by eventdate) as c, 
 rank() over (partition by userid, siteid order by eventdate) as rank
 from views
```

My current version of hive (10.0) does not support windowing functions, and does not support sub queries in the from clause i.e

```
 select userid, clicks from clicktable where userid in usertable
```

Comment: Note that windowing functions were introduced in Hive 11.

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to write this is as a correlated subquery.  But, you can also do this using a join, aggregation, and conditional aggregation functions:

```
select v.userid, v.siteid, v.eventdate,
       count(*) as c,
       count(distinct case when v2.eventdate <= v.eventdate then v2.eventdate end) as rank
from views v left outer join
     views v2 
     on v.userid = v2.userid and
        v.siteid = v2.siteid
group by v.userid, v.siteid, v.eventdate;
```